# Vertically Responsive Web Design

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am using HTML5, CSS3, JS1.8.5 to create a responsive website. For experimentation purposes, I was wondering if it is possible to make my website vertically responsive too, and how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Use media queries too :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As as @www139 saying up there, you could use vh/vw units. Vh (stands for view height) would work to make your website vertically responsive. One vh equals 1 percent of the screens height. For an example lets say I have this code:

```css
div {
 font-size:10vh 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>This is the text!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As the screen decreases in height, the text side will shrink. The other way your could do it would be media query's:

```css
@media screen and (max-height: 500px) {
  font-size:10px;
}
div {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>Text is great! :)</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now if the screen height is smaller than 500 pixels then the styles in between the curly braces. The last way to go would be to use `height:100%` or whatever percentage you want.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sikez no problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

**CSS**

```
body,html{height:100%; //if you want to control by percentage}

@media screen and ( max-height: 600px ){
    //something
}
```

to control layout dynamically, use javascript to measure screen height and do your needful

**JS**

```
$(window).height();
```